# How do I manually clear cache for webview in Chrome app?

Tags: caching, google-chrome-extension, webview, google-chrome-app

I am developing a Chrome app that shows some web content in a webview tag. The content is being cached. When I edit the content files, clearing Chrome browsers' cache does not seem to actually clear the webview cache.

One of the posts recommends to assign a unique partition ID every time Chrome app starts.
Changing partition ID on the webview does help to clear (or re allocate) the cache, but I still would like to take advantage of caching 3MB of web content and clear it manually only if it changes.

Is there a way to clear that cache, in particular on Chrome OS?

Comment: Looks like there is no way right now: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=406437

Comment: @rsanchez You should make that into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This has since been [implemented](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=406437) and is available in Chrome 43+

```
webviewElement.clearData({}, {cache: true}, function() {
  // Cache cleared
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks for following up. Originally I was looking for a way to clear it using browser's UI, but with this code I can add a clear cache button in my chrome app.