# How to clear the local storage and session storage in Webview Chrome App?

Tags: webview, refresh, google-chrome-app, browser-cache

I am developing chrome app using webview(https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview). I cleared the cache using (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-ClearDataOptions) but Webview URL refreshing its takes 5 to 10 mins.Do you have any idea on this?

i tried this:

```
var clearDataType = {
appcache: true,
cache: true, // remove entire cache.
cookies: true,
}

webview.clearData({ since: 0 }, clearDataType, function() {
// Reload webview after clearing browsing data.
});
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the [solution of KENdi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38139360/5995040)? Also check [clear website cache in a <webview> ](https://plus.sandbox.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/J6zm2bjF8et) for more information. Did you check the logs if there are warnings or errors causing it to take 5 to 10 mins?